# Number Next To Name||Destiny 2

Tags: destiny-2

I've noticed a lot of people ask this question, but I just don't understand.

If the number next to the name is the seasonal rank like people say, how can someone have a level of 222 or 261? Seasonal ranks only go up to 100.

Comment: How I understand it is that *rewards* stop at rank 100. Everything after that is prestige. But I’m only rank 72ish, so I’m not sure if that premise is correct

Comment: ^ The same answer there would apply to this question making it a duplicate.

Comment: This question can be reworded to ask why the number goes beyond the season pass reward limit.  Otherwise it would be a duplicate and should be closed.

Comment: @DavidYell Hi, I have already read that thread, and it doesn't answer my question at all. I realize it's supposedly Season Rank level, I just don't understand how it would go past 100, since, as far as I can tell, that's the highest level.

Comment: I would have to thank @Wondercricket for the only real answer here :)

Comment: Please feel free to reword your question to differentiate it from the duplicate, and it can be re-opened. Although I feel the answer is obvious if you've played the game

Comment: The season pass itself only has 100 levels. You can progress above it, and while you don't get any special rewards for doing that, you do get XP that levels your seasonal artifact up, which in turn gives you light levels, and you get a bright engram every 5 levels above 100.